# docker image multistage build: How to create a docker image copying only python packages

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a python based image with some packages installed. But i want the image layer not to show anything about the packages I installed.

I am trying to use the multistage build

eg:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster as builder
RUN pip install django # (I dont want this command to be seen when checking the docker image layers, So thats why using multistage build)

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
# Here i want to copy all the site packages
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Now build image

```
docker build -t python_3.9-slim-buster_custom:latest .
```

and later check the image layers

```
dive python_3.9-slim-buster_custom:latest
```

this will not show the `RUN pip install django` line

Will this be a good way to achieve what i want (hide all the pip install commands)

Comment: You will always be able to run _e.g._ `docker run --rm your-image pip list` to see what's installed, even if the command isn't in the `docker history`.

Comment: thats fine. But i want  a clean image. Because i will be using some setup.py files to install some packages. Which i dont want to be know to others. They can access the package from site-packages, thats fine. Just want to hide the way things are installed

Comment: will this be sufficient or should i also have to copy some other folders too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are installing, if this will be sufficient or not. Some python libraries add binaries to your system on which they rely.

```sh
FROM python:3.9-alpine as builder
# install stuff


FROM python:3.9-alpine

# this is for sure required
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

# this depends on what you are installing
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Can i copy the whole root folder is that possible. Like `COPY --from=builder / /`

Comment: Better not, because usually you want to avoid copying the tool chain and things it needed to install the packages. This is especially true for alpine, where you need to build the wheel yourself. In order to get a slim final stage, you should only copy what really matters. Namely, the produced packages and binaries.

Comment: I tried `COPY --from=builder / /`, it did worked.

Comment: Sure it works, but it can lead to a bigger image than required. Usually you want to aim for a small image.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach I see for this is to use a virtual environment in an earlier build stage, then copy the entire virtual environment into the final image.  Remember that virtual environments are very specific to a single Python build and installation path.

If your application has its own `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` file, then a minimal version of this could look like:

```sh
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster as builder

# If you need build-only tools, like build-essential for Python C
# extensions, install them first
# RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...

WORKDIR /src

# Create and "activate" the virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /app
ENV PATH=/app/bin:$PATH

# Install the application as normal
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install .

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster as builder

# If you need runtime libraries, like a database client C library,
# install them first
# RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install ...

# Copy the entire virtual environment over
COPY --from=builder /app /app
ENV PATH=/app/bin:$PATH

# Run an entry_points script from the setup.cfg as the main command
CMD ["my_app"]
```

Note that this has only minimal protection against a curious user seeing what's in the image.  The `docker history` or `docker inspect` output will show the `/app` container directory, you can `docker run --rm the-image pip list` to see the package dependencies, and the application and library source will be present in a human-readable form.

Answer (score -7):

Currently whats working for me is.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster as builder
# DO ALL YOUR STUFF HERE

FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
COPY --from=builder / /
```

Comment: If you just copy the whole root there's no advantage of doing multi-stage building